# Real world applications of Riemann surfaces of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, riemann-surfaces, applications, analytic-continuation

The maximal analytic continuation of a holomorphic function is an example of Riemann surfaces.

What is it  used for?

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I want to know the applications related to the real world  rather than pure mathematics.

Comment: Though it is said to be too broad, I don't know any examples.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89072/applications-of-analytic-continuation-to-physics